# Mouse Pointer Lag issue

Tags: updates, display, mouse, playonlinux

i have installed latest elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki and was doing bit of searching about tips and tricks for getting tweaks but in the process got a very annoying problem.
i have a wireless mouse. when i try to move it after when its in rest for like 5 seconds for making it move again i have to shake it for few times then the pointer again starts moving. while touchpad has no such issues.
please check the video for my issue
[video of the issue](https://photos.app.goo.gl/FfzWczNMivdnEa7W2)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but not as bad as yours.

Try the following commands in terminal:

`$ sudo modprobe -r peaq_wmi`

`$ sudo modprobe -r eeepc_wmi`